# Hibernate - failed to lazily initialize a collection of role - could not initialize proxy - no Session

Tags: spring, hibernate, dao

Issue: Cannot add `Address` object via `User` object inside a Spring `Controller`.

`User` and `Address` classes -> `@Entity`

`User` has a `List<Address>` with `FetchType=LAZY`

```
@Repository
public class UserDao{
    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;
    ...
    public User get(String username) {
        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        return (User)session.get(User.class, username);
    }
    ...
    public void update(User user){
        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        session.saveOrUpdate(user);
    }
    ...
}


@Service
@Transnational
public class UserService{
    @AutoWired
    private UserDao userDao;
    ...

    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public User get(String username) {
        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        return (User)session.get(User.class, username);
    }

    public void update(User user){
        userDao.update(user);
    } 
    ...
}

@Controller
public class UserController{
    @AutoWired
    private UserService userService;
    ....
    public String update(){
        User user = userService.get("user0001");
        user.getAddressList.add(new Address("new street"));
        return "update";
    }
}
```

Spring.xml

```
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="location">
        <value>classpath:jdbc.properties</value>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="dataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource">
    <property name="driverClass" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}" />
    <property name="jdbcUrl" value="${jdbc.url}" />
    <property name="user" value="${jdbc.username}" />
    <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}" />
</bean>

<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource">
        <ref bean="dataSource"/>
    </property>
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.entity" />
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
       <props>
         <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
         <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.show_sql}</prop>
       </props>
    </property> 
</bean>
```

Everything is working fine. But I cannot make changes to the `user` object inside a `@Controller`.

When `user` object is getting change in `@Controller` level, there is no such Hibernate session involves with the object. Somehow the object is out of the hibernate context.

Error happens at `.add(new Address("new street"));` statement in `@Controller`.

Why it is prohibited to change an object inside a `Controller` which is received via Hibernate session?

The way I followed is incorrect? If not what have I done wrong?

--Spring 4, Hibernate 4

Answer (score 3):

`User` has a `List<Address>`. When you fetch the user from the database rather then a list, hibernate inserts a proxy that handles the fetching of the addresses.

This proxy needs to have a session to be able to do anything. When you try to add an address you are outside the scope of the transactional annotation, thus there is no session.

Best way to get you going would be to add a method annotated with `@Transactional` in the `UserService` that adds an address.

Comment: Yes. I tried that and it worked. Can you explain a little bit in your answer about `proxy`? Can't we instruct there proxies to NOT to respond at once? However `Controller` has no idea about a proxy which is hibernate or anything. So there is a coupling + rule which is "do not update objects/entities inside `Controllers`". Is this OK?

Comment: You're using two systems at the same time, Spring and Hibernate. They both do things for you to make your life easier but you need to understand what each one does. 

Hibernate works with a concept of transactions. You create a session, fetch some objects, alter them and commit them to the database, then you close the session. If any exceptions occur your roll back and abort. This is called a transaction. You can read more about it here: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/transactions.html

Comment: Now writing all this boiler plate code every time is bloody waste of every ones time. So this is where the `@Transactional` annotation comes in. By adding this to a method you tell the framework (Spring in this case) to wrap the boiler plate code for the session around the method.

Comment: The confusion sets in once the object leaves this method. Once it leaves the method, the transactional code that is wrapped around the method cleans up and closes the session. When Hibernate fetched the object for you it added a proxy to allow you to fetch the collection lazily (more wrapping of boiler plate code!). However the proxy needs this session to be able to do anything. Yet this session was closed down when the object left the scope of the transaction. Because the session is closed it can't fetch or add data.

Comment: If you'd written the transaction boiler plate code yourself you'd be able to see very quickly that you're trying to do something to your data after you've closed the session. Now this is hidden by the magic of `@Transactional` keyword.

Comment: TLDR: The rule is: Don't alter your data outside of a transaction. This also means you could probably do away with the DAO and the Service and just use a Controller per user that handles the modifications but that isn't really my area of expertise.

Comment: Appendum: Another thing to avoid is sharing data between sessions. This may lead to a state state. So don't take an object you fetched in one transaction and use it in another transaction.

Comment: And another thing to watch for is this: The transaction management is done through a bean. Instead of getting your UserService you get a bean that wraps your user service. So if you enter the user service through a method that was annotated with `@Transactional` everything will be inside the transaction until you leave through the bean. Calling another method will also put that into the transactional scope. However if you enter the UserService through a method that isn't annotated and then try to use a method that is, you won't have a session.

Comment: My question is, I can use either `Spring JDBC`, `Hibernate`, etc to fetch an entity. But why `Controller` needs to know about this LAZY loading and PROXIES. To the `Controller` it is just an object. Can you point me to some source which is about "TLDR: The rule is: Don't alter your data outside of a transaction."

Comment: Not really. It is a logical derivative of 1) having a lazily fetched collection 2) lazy fetching needing a session to fetch data (with or w/o hibernate) 3) a session only existing in transaction scope and 4) and you wanting to modify the lazy collection.